# STPolyFromText polígonos abarca todo el mundo en sql server spatial references

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

estoy intentando mostrar el resultado un poligono que forme a base de coordenadas pero lo único que regresa es como si estuviera seleccionando un polígono del mundo este es el querie que estoy haciendo:

`SELECT geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((-90.5014125623488 14.6237259680121, -90.50181355258134 14.624190529445599,-90.50156813046577 14.624378689523088, -90.50152655622762 14.624717377256234, -90.50017204072644 14.624551277590314, -90.5014125623488 14.6237259680121))', 4326);`

debería regresar un pequeño polígono pero regresa toda la pantalla en verde.

simir a lo que debería regresar:
[image: buena imagen]

lo que regresa:
[image: mal resultado]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Historia corta**: tu polígono está al revés. si quieres encerrar esa área debes definir los puntos en contra del reloj.

**Historia larga**: la actualización de [la especificación GeoJSON de 2016](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946) indica que:

> o  A linear ring MUST follow the right-hand rule with respect to the
> area it bounds, i.e., exterior rings are counterclockwise, and
> holes are clockwise.

De manera que lo que tienes en esa geometría es la resultante de "todo el planeta menos un cierto polígono".

La especificación, además de haber sido escasamente comunicada, recomienda además que los parsers existentes sean tolerantes a errores en miras de la retrocompatibilidad. Vale decir: algunos lo interpretan como tú esperas y otros justo al revés.

Adjunto un gist mostrando la geometría original y la corregida: https://gist.github.com/ffflabs/c41cbb1c27dda63823f8482b20960c9b